# Is there a way we can load properties from src/test/resources/application.properties in spring boot test?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc-test

```
    @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(MyClass.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:application-test.yml")
```

//Something like this?

Answer (score 0):

This should still able to find the properties in the test file in your application:

```java
@Autowired
private Environment env;

// Load data
String data = env.getProperty("some.property")
```